# Why does my code produces a different solution than the official solution?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve a puzzle of 'Advent of code', which entails finding out how many passwords are valid of a list of passwords and their policicy.

But my code returns always **627** instead **474**, which is the official solution to my puzzle input.

Can someone explain what could be wrong?

The puzzle:
[AdventOfCode_2020_Day2](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/2)

My puzzle input:
[GoogleDrive_PuzzleInput](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uxYs0KLtL1pJU59EuRsiOp0hHCZEkI_d/view?usp=sharing)

```
    public static void Day2()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int result = 0;
        string[] text = ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Kcir\Documents\Programming\myapp\day2.txt");
        string[] policy = new string[text.Length];
        string[] corrupted = new string[text.Length];
        int[] min = new int[text.Length];
        int[] max = new int[text.Length];

        foreach (string x in text)
        {

            policy[i] = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(":") - 1, 1);
            min[i] = Int32.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf("-")));
            max[i] = Int32.Parse(x.Substring(x.IndexOf("-") + 1, 2));
            corrupted[i] = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(":") + 2);
            i++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < corrupted.Length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < max[i]; j++)
            {
                if (corrupted[i].Contains(policy[i]))
                {
                    corrupted[i] = corrupted[i].Substring(corrupted[i].IndexOf(policy[i]) + 1);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count >= min[i] && count <= max[i])
            {
                result++;
            }
        }
        WriteLine("Number of valid passwords: " + result);
    }
```

Comment: Questions need to stand by themselves here. You need to put enough description, input and output in the question itself (not links). Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop condition is bad - your algorithm will never count more than the policy’s max value

Comment: Thats it! I changed the line to `j<20` and now it returns the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't check all letters in the corrupted array. The first occurance of wrong counting is the 6th case which is `5-14 t: ttttnttttttdttttttt`. There are 17 letters need to be checked but you only check the first 14 ones. I suggest you to learn how to debug. See my screenshot, the corrupted[i] still has 3 letters left but your code exit the loop.

[image]

I've simplified your code (no need lots of arrays) and fixed the bug (check all letters):

```
void Main()
{
    var valid = 0;
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\day2.txt");
    foreach (var line in data)
    {
        var letter = line[line.IndexOf(":") - 1];                           // letter in policy
        var min =  Int32.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf("-")));       // minimum count in policy
        var max = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("-") + 1, 2));    // maximum count in policy
        var password = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 2);               // password need to be verified
        var count = 0;                                                      // count of letter in password
        foreach (var l in password)                                         // loop all letters in password
        {
            if (l == letter) count++;                                       // increment number of letters found in password
        }
        if (count >= min && count <= max) valid++;                          // increment number of valid passwords
    }
    Console.WriteLine(valid);
}
```

Result in LinqPad:

[image]